# Can I apply for a UK visa as soon as my existing visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk

I am from an Asian country and I have an existing UK visa that will expire on November 30, 2016. I've visited the UK twice. July-August 2016 for 3 weeks and October for 2 weeks and I am planning to go back to the UK again.

My question is: Can I apply for a UK visa as soon as my existing visa expires? Or do I need to wait for another year since they say that you are only given a 6 months visa in a year?

Comment: It seems like you're spending nearly as much time in the UK as you are outside it, which is generally inconsistent with what they want you to be doing on a visitor visa. That can be a problem if you apply for another visa so quickly. What's the purpose of your visits?

Comment: i am a frequent traveler. I still have Schengen Visa that is valid for 1 year. since i have limited time to visit and explore UK on my previous travel. i am planning to go back. it will be my main entry then will go to europe and exit again in UK.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing stopping you applying.  However, the UK government may want assurances that you are a) merely a 'frequent traveller' as you suggest, and not b) trying to live/work in the UK and merely 'renewing' a visa to get back into the country to continue a life there.

As such, supporting paperwork of evidence of your life in your home country can be of use - employment evidence, lease on apartment, and an itinerary of your trip in the UK, with bookings or contacts, if any investigation on their part is required - you're showing your clear intentions to merely be a tourist, rather than anything else.

The rules governing your application are in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).